# Rename factors in a spineplot with R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to rename `factor`'s in a `spineplot`? The names of my factors are to long, so they overlap.

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible example? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the help for `spineplot`, it is clear that you can pass the parameters `yaxlabels` and `xaxlabels` to control the vectors for annotation of the axes.

One useful function is `abbreviate` which will shorten character strings.

Combining this information with the `spineplot` example gives:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2),
    labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),
    levels = c(1, 2, 3),
    labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))

spineplot(improved ~ treatment, yaxlabels=abbreviate(levels(improved), 2))
```

[image]

Not all of the plot functions in R have this type of parameter.  For a more general solution, it might be necessary to rename the factors before passing to a plot function.  You can access and modify factor names using the `levels` function:

```
levels(treatment) <- abbreviate(levels(treatment), 5)
plot(improved ~ treatment)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Andrie! Thanks for your thoughts. I extended your example to exactly the problem that I've got. The extended version of your code might be `numberofdrugs<-rpois(84, 2)` 

`xtabs(numberofdrugs~improved+treatment)`

`plot(xtabs(numberofdrugs~improved+treatment))`     .So this is not exactly a spineplot, it is a visualization of a contingency table :) Sorry, I thought this is the same. How can I adjust the the labels in this kind of plot? `yaxlabels` doesn't work

Comment: @user734124 I'm glad that helped.  Now please start to accept some of the answers you have received.

Comment: Hmm I don't know what you mean.... `plot(xtabs(numberofdrugs~improved+treatment),yaxlabels=abbreviate(levels(improved), 2))` doesn't work when it's not a spineplot! Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: OK. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the Labels are above the plot (not as in your example in the spineplot) :( So it seems that R is putting the labels above the plot, when plotting a contingency table. Is there a way to say R to put the Labels below the plot?

Comment: Anything is possible in R.  But this sounds like a different question.  It depends on the type of plot you are using.  Post a new question, this time with some example data and code, and someone is bound to answer.